# strcat does not work for second item in for loop only

Tags: c, cs50

I'm currently doing HarvardX's CS50 course. The goal of the exercise I'm currently facing is to output all winners in an election when they are tied. As I don't need the output afterwards, I thought adding them all to a string with a line break in between would work out. It did work out, but only for election winners 1 and 3, 4, 5 etc. For one reason or another, it doesn't work for the second iteration in the for loop and I have no clue why.

This is the function to print out the winner:

```
void print_winner(void)
{
    string most_votes;
    int highest_vote = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {

            if(candidates[i].votes > highest_vote)
            {
                most_votes = candidates[i].name;
                highest_vote = candidates[i].votes;
            }
            else if(candidates[i].votes == highest_vote)
            {
                printf("Name %i: %s\n", i, candidates[i].name);
                most_votes = strcat(most_votes, "\n");
                most_votes = strcat(most_votes, candidates[i].name);
                printf("%s\n", most_votes);
            }
    }

    printf("%s\n", most_votes);

    return;
```

Point of interest is the else-if statement. It does work and for every iteration, it prints out the name of the candidate correctly except for the second one. When I print most_votes at the bottom of the if-else statement I get:

*For two candidates*

```
a
```

*For three candidates*

```
a

c
```

*For four candidates*

```
a

c
d
```

I have no clue why b is falling away, as printing out candidates[b].name does give b. I'm probably overlooking something very simple, but I have no idea what.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I expected that I made a simple mistake, but it seems that's not necessarily the case. 
I now know the problem is in this line:

```
most_votes = strcat(most_votes, "\n");
```

Deleting it resolves the problem, but as I do need the line break this does not resolve the problem for me. Replacing the line break for other strings does not change the result, so maybe using strcat on the same variable twice in a row is problematic? I don't know.

If anyone wants to try out, the whole code can be found here:
[Github](https://github.com/me50/riknijhuis1/blob/cs50/problems/2020/x/plurality/plurality.c)

Comment: `string` is an alias of `char *` in CS50.  You need to reserve space for this `string most_votes` if you want to use `strcat`, i.e.: `string most_votes = malloc(256);`

Comment: What is the input for the each candidate?

Comment: @DavidRanieri thanks for helping. This didn't solve the problem, unfortunately - it compiled correctly but the output is still the same.

Comment: @Karthick:
candidate 0: a, 1 vote
candidate 1: b, 1 vote
candidate 2: c, 1 vote
candidate 3: d, 1 vote

Comment: @DavidRanieri I just noticed that once I delete the line that adds the line break (most_votes = strcat(most_votes, "\n");), the problem goes away. Do you think this is related to memory allocation?

Comment: @Rik: Try `calloc` instead of `malloc` in order to set all values to 0 (`strcat` wants a null-terminated string): `string most_votes = calloc(1, 256);`

Comment: @DavidRanieri, thanks again. Unfortunately, it's still not giving the expected output.

Comment: After using the `calloc` suggested by @DavidRanieri, your line `most_votes = candidates[i].name;` then invalidates the allocated pointer (if I understand the cs50 'string' alias correctly). Try `strcpy(most_votes,candidates[i].name);` in the `if` block, instead.

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks for helping. I tried your solution but to no avail. Not using strcpy was probably part of the problem though as the answer also includes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the memory of the first candidate's name for the entire list of names and thus changes his name. 
Obviously this is not what you want. It is also possible that you overflow the name buffer. Try this:

```
void print_winner(void)
{
    char most_votes[1000];
    int highest_vote = -1; /* force a new high score with the first candidate*/
    most_votes[0] = '\0'; /*valid string in case of no votes at all*/

    for(int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(candidates[i].votes > highest_vote) /*new high score*/
        {
           strcpy(most_votes, candidates[i].name);
           highest_vote = candidates[i].votes;
        }
        else if(candidates[i].votes == highest_vote)
        {
           printf("Name %i: %s\n", i, candidates[i].name);
           strcat(most_votes, "\n");
           strcat(most_votes, candidates[i].name);
           printf("%s\n", most_votes);
        }
    }
    printf("The winner(s) with %i votes:\n%s\n", highest_vote, most_votes);
}
```